# How do I extract the tags that are NOT in the db?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

The `Ruby` and `C` tags exist in the db.

```
Tag.where(:name => ["Ruby", "C", "foo", "bar"]).map(&:name)
```

Returns: `["Ruby", "C"]`.

How do I return the tags that aren't in the db. So the opposite. i.e. `["foo", "bar"]`

Looking for an elegant Ruby one liner solution. If possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
search_tags = ["Ruby", "C", "foo", "bar"]
not_found = search_tags - Tag.where(:name => search_tags).map(&:name)
```

Just a quick answer with mostly copy/pasting what you already had, adjust as needed.

Comment: +1 for the minus sign on arrays... hadn't seen that before :)

Comment: @tybro: Then you might also want to look at `Array#&` and `Array#|`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the following would do that in one line:

```
["Ruby", "C", "foo", "bar"].reject { |name| Tag.where(:name => name) }
```

But it's not fast, because it will take 4 queries.